# Add prop to image HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Wanted to see if anyone knows how to add props to a image with HTML5 so I would have a image load then add glasses to the image then save the image want to do this with all HTML5 and JS if able to if anyone has a idea please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `<canvas>` element to do image manipulation using HTML and JS.

Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas

EDIT:

Drawing Images onto the canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Have a look at `toDataURL` to save the image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: I understand that just the steps on how you would do that with the mapping of the overlays and then the saving.

Comment: That kinda does what i want but I need the "props" to be able to be moved around.

Comment: canvas does not support moving objects by itself, you would have to calculate the coordinates for the overlayed images yourself and redraw the canvas continously to create an "animation".